# Migrated a document library from classic, it has now broken my SharePoint online site navigation, how to fix?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have moved a Document Library from SharePoint classic 2010 into SharePoint Online using the free Microsoft migration tool.

Since doing this my navigation has broken on the SharePoint Online site, and I feel like some of the classic stuff has infected my modern site/environment.

Broken (After migration):
[image]

Any idea how I can fix this? :(

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure < Turn this off in the site collection features settings and it will fix the navigation. Not sure why this was turned on when doing the library migration!